# SQL order by elements from IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `ITEM` table and I'd like to return results ordered by the same order informed in a IN clause. These IDs are informed by the user.

Today I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ITEM
WHERE ITEM_ID IN (45,2,671,6)
ORDER BY CASE ITEM_ID 
  WHEN 45 THEN 0
  WHEN 2 THEN 1
  WHEN 671 THEN 2
  WHEN 6 THEN 3
END
```

This works but `CASE` has a [limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) of 65535 arguments which is giving me `ORA-00939: too many arguments for function` when I need more than that.

Is there an alternative solution for Oracle, without limits and preferably with good performance and accepted in other DBMS as well?

Thanks

Comment: You will hit the 1000 limit for items in the list in the `IN` condition long before you hit the limit for `case` expressions. The proper way to do this, both for the `in` and the `case` expression, is to have the values in a table, with another column by which to order. Then join and use that other column for ordering. Solve both "limit" problems at once. When the values are in a table (not in a hard-coded list) there is no limit - and the approach is DBMS independent.

Comment: @mathguy actually I split the `IN` clause in groups of 1000s. So are you suggesting that I add all the values (informed by the user) in a temporary table? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, pretty much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your logic and above solutions are good for small scale, if you are talking about more than 65000 items, you need a solution which is scalable.

My suggestion is to split this task to 2 steps.

**Step 1**

Create a temporary table,
This temporary table will have 3 columns minumum

```
TEMP_ITEM_ORDER_TABLE (
  session_key varchar2(50),
  item_id number,
  item_report_order number
)
```

Each time user orders such a query, insert data ,i.e item ids and their sequence no into this temporary table with some unique key to identify user session (possibly user id or session id). This trick is to avoid collision of item lists when multiple users simultaneously fire reports.

**Step 2**

Now fire your report query joining your main table, temp table with `session_key`. In the query order data based on your input order (stored in temp table already)

```
SELECT 
  T1.* , T2.item_report_order
FROM ITEM T1, TEMP_ITEM_ORDER_TABLE T2
  WHERE T1.ITEM_ID = T2.ITEM_ID
  AND T2.session_key = :input_session_key
  ORDER BY t2.item_report_order
```

This method is

1. database agnostic
2. scalable with any number of inputs
3. Gives best possible performance

Note: To further improve query performance, create index on session_key, item_id in temp table also create index on item_id on ITEM table (if not exists already)

Edit:
Oracle offers [Global Temporary Table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) feature, which creates has features to allow records only with in session and auto clean up upon commit/end of session etc. You can make use of this feature and avoid session key, but this solution can not be replicated on other database products unless they support similar feature.

Comment: Since on Oracle the data is visible only to the session that inserted it, I assume I would not need `session_key` right?

Comment: I would still recommend to use a session key. If some data is committed to table from some other session, then select statement will pick up data from those records as well, which is not desired result.

Comment: Besides, I do not know your application architecture, if it uses single database connection or multiple , also do not know if it allows only 1 report or multiple reports at a time. Depending on all these, you will have to design a clean up mechanism to delete records from temp table when no longer needed. If you want to avoid session key, an Oracle specific solution is to use Global temporary table (https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables). It will handle deleting records upon session termination/transaction termination as well. But this can not be used across other DBs

Answer (score 1):

Where are the elements coming from?  I would suggest that you use a `join`:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM ITEM i JOIN
     (SELECT 45 as id, 1 as ord FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as id, 2 as ord FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 671 as id, 3 as ord FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 as id, 4 as ord FROM DUAL
     ) x
     ON i.ITEM_ID = x.id
ORDER BY x.ord;
```

This is simpler if the ids come from a table with the relevant information.

Comment: The IDs are informed by the user in an HTML form field. But with your solution I would have more than 35K `UNION ALL` operations... would this have good performance? Thanks!

Comment: How does a use put in thousands of values in an HTML form field?  I would suggest that you load the values into a table.

Comment: Just copying and pasting. I guess this solution would be the best to my case then right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5886510

Comment: @qxlab . . . Yes.  However, the answer would be better if it suggested that the value be a primary key or have an index.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a temporary table, instead you can use a collection:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   ITEM i
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                COLUMN_VALUE AS value
         FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 45, 2, 671, 6 ) )
       ) v
       ON ( i.ITEM_ID = v.VALUE )
ORDER BY v.RN;
```

It can even be passed in as a [bind variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM   ITEM i
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                COLUMN_VALUE AS value
         FROM   TABLE( :your_array )
       ) v
       ON ( i.ITEM_ID = v.VALUE )
ORDER BY v.RN;
```